# How to add additional separators to the standard tokenizer?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

Given this text (example from nginx logs)

> 646#646: *226999 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 192.0.2.0, server: 0.0.0.0:443

the `standard` tokenizer produces

```
646
646
226999
ssl_do_handshake
failed
ssl
error
1417d18c:ssl
routines:tls_process_client_hello:version
too
low
while
ssl
handshaking
client
192.0.2.0
server
0.0.0.0
443
```

I would like the tokens `1417d18c:ssl` and `routines:tls_process_client_hello:version` to be additional split on the `:`. However, I do not want the `ssl_do_handshake` or `192.0.2.0` to be split any further nor should e.g. `can't` be tokenised to `can`, `t`.

Is there a way to apply additional splitting after a built-in tokenizer?

Am I stuck with using `pattern`? In which case what regular expression duplicates the behaviour of `standard`?

Comment: Have you tried using a ```Char Group Tokenizer```? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-chargroup-tokenizer.html

Comment: @Jono how would you make sure that tokenises words in single quotes, but doesn't strip the apostrophes from within words?

Comment: Oh that's a tricky one. Only way you can really distinguish is by white space before and after the word in single quotes (if it's there). You could perhaps try and analyze using one tokenizer which tokenizes ```" '"``` and ```"' "``` and then analyze again based on whitespace. I haven't tried it out though so not sure if that would work

Comment: @Jono that's why I'm asking the question. The `standard` tokeniser handles that, and it looks like the `pattern` tokeniser is the only other one that could. If you can chain a `charset` after a `standard`, then please provide an answer showing how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to add on to the standard analyzers. If you are ok with what standard analyzer does and just additionally want the produced tokens to further get tokenised by `:` then you can define standard analyzer as your custom analyzer as give [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition) and add a [pattern capture token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) to further tokenize the tokens produced by the standard tokenizer.

So define the analyzer and token filter as below:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "logs": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "log"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "log": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "patterns": [
            "([^:]+)"
          ],
          "preserve_original" : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, although Kibana's highlighting appears to still use the original tokens.